# How, in three dimensions, is tangent line defined in the case $f'(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analytic-geometry, tangent-line

Let $f:(a\,..b)\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$. Let $f$ be differentiable on $(a\,..b)$, where $f'(x)=\big(f_x'(x),f_y'(x),f_z'(x)\big)$. Let $0$ mean the zero vector.

First, we know that the line must pass through $f(x_0)$. Second, it must also pass through $f(x_0)+f'(x_0)$.

The case is easy when the points are unequal - in other words, $f(x_0)\neq f'(x_0)+f(x_0)$. In this situation, we can use the popular equation of a line passing through two different points $\alpha$ and $\beta$: $l(x)=x \alpha +(1-x) \beta$, which here becomes $t(x)=x(f(x_0)+f'(x_0))+(1-x)f(x_0)$. Defining a tangent poses no problem in this case.

What, however, about the case $f'(x_0)=0$? Here the equation above becomes useless - $f(x_0)+f'(x_0)=f(x_0)$, and therefore we can't use the formula to define a tangent to $f(x_0)$.

The tangent line intuitively exists in at least some of such cases - for example, if we take each of the components of $f(x_0)$ to be a local maximum, then $f'(x_0)=0$ and yet we intuitively know that a line tangent to $f(x_0)$.

How to define such a line in this case, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that it is not appropriate to *define*
the tangent line of a curve defined by some arbitrary three-dimensional
function $f(t) = (f_x(t), f_y(t),  f_z(t))$ at $f(t_0)$
as the line that passes through the points 
$f(t_0)$ and $f(t_0) + f'(t_0).$
I think it is true that when a tangent line exists at $f(t_0)$ and the
derivative $f'(t_0)$ also exists,
then the tangent line passes through $f(t_0) + f'(t_0).$

If it happens that $f'(t_0) \neq 0,$ then this relationship enables us
to identify the tangent line at $f(t).$
But consider the curve defined by
$$
f(t) = \left(\cos\left(\frac\pi2 t^3\right),
             \sin\left(\frac\pi2 t^3\right), 0\right)
$$
for $t \in [-1,1].$
This is a semicircle through $(0,-1,0),$ $(1,0,0),$ and $(0,1,0),$
traced once in the direction from $(0,-1,0)$ to $(0,1,0),$ 
and it clearly has a tangent at $(1,0,0)$ even though $f'(0) = (0,0,0).$

You can resolve problems like this by defining tangent more carefully.
See ["The Definition of a Tangent to a Curve" by T. M. Flett](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S0950184300003153), for example, which mentions that

> It  must  be  emphasised  that  there  is  no  correlation  between  the
>   existence  of  (continuous)  tangents  and  the  existence   of   (continuous) derivatives.

One resolution of the problem would be to make the tangent at $f(t_0)$ a limit of the secant lines through points on the curve in the neighborhood
of $f(t_0).$ But you have to be careful how you define that limit.

A quicker resolution of the problem would be to
require that the tangent be defined always relative to a
parameterization of the curve by a function $f$ such that $f' \neq 0.$
This leads you to look at "regular paths" as defined in the answer by Andrew D. Hwang.

Answer (score 4):

If a smooth path $f$ satisfies $f'(x_{0}) = 0$ for some $x_{0}$, there *may* exist a tangent line to the image, but there *need not* exist a tangent line:

- The smooth path $f(x) = (x^{3}, 0, 0)$ traces the $x$-axis, which has a tangent line at $0$, but $f'(0) = 0$.
- The smooth path $f(x) = (\cos^{3} x, \sin^{3} x, 0)$ traces an [astroid curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid), which fails to have a tangent line at each cusp (i.e., when $x$ is an integer multiple of $\pi/2$).

This is why, in differential geometry, one focuses not on *smooth* (differentiable to some degree) paths, but on *regular* paths (smooth, and with nowhere-vanishing derivative).

It may help to notice that a graph $y = g(x)$ may be parametrized by $f(x) = (x, g(x))$. If $g$ is smooth, then $f'(x) = (1, g'(x))$, so $f$ is regular as long as $g$ is smooth. This is likely the origin of your intuition that "every smooth path has a tangent line".

Comment: What does a "non-vanishing derivative" mean?

Comment: A derivative that is nowhere zero; precisely, $f:(a, b) \to \mathbf{R}^{3}$ has _nowhere-vanishing derivative_ if $f'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t$ in $(a, b)$.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the line goes away in a different direction, for example (t2,t2,t|t|)
arrives along (1,1,1) and leaves along (1,1,−1).

If the functions are smooth, you can take Taylor series, and use the leading-order that involves $t$, so $(2+t^2+t^3,1+2t^2-t^3,3+6t^2)$ has tangent in direction $(1,2,6)$

You might re-parametrise, so in the previous case, let $t=\sqrt{u}$ and, at least for positive $t$, the leading-order is $(2+u,1+2u,3+6u)$

Answer (score 1):

The derivative you have defined is a vector (of course). It tells you both the direction and the speed (the length of the derivative) of motion along the curve as the parameter $x$ increases. It may happen that the speed is (momentarily) $0$ - but that can depend on the parameterization. If you replace $x$ by some smooth monotone increasing function of $x$ you will change the speeds but not the directions of the tangent vectors. It's usual to choose a parameterization that never has velocity $0$. The natural parameter is the arclength of the curve. That may not be easy to compute in a particular example (the integral can be ugly) but it makes the most geometric sense.